# Issues with ubuntu restart

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Recently I installed the Nvidia-CUDA package. It asked me for a restart. After restart, my pc starts but doesn't load the desktop (after logging in)[image: This is what I get after restart]. How do I recover? I need to do it since most of my research data is in here. Note: I am running Ubuntu on VMWare player.

Comment: Can you access a tty? (Ctrl+Alt+F1) If so try removing the CUDA packages.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t ask me why, but when I have booting issues, I boot with the live usb stick, choose install and then abort it. After a normal reboot sometimes it fixes what I broke..